# Error when deploying to Mumbai Test net "gas required exceeds allowance"

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment, gas, polygon

I've written a very simple smart contract in Solidity and I'm trying to deploy it to the test net to make sure that I have not made any mistakes or anything when writing my code. The smart contract is as follows:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.3.0/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";    
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.3.0/access/Ownable.sol";        

contract MyToken is ERC721, Ownable {
    uint256 public totalCount;                          // Describes the number of NFTs available for minting
    uint256 public mintedCount;                         // Describes the number of NFTs minted so far
    mapping(uint256 => bool) private tokenAvailablity;  // Describes which tokens are taken and which are available

    constructor() public ERC721("MyToken", "MTKN") {
        totalCount = 2000;              // 2022 tokens are available when the contract is created
        mintedCount  = 0;               // No tokens have been minted initially

        // Generating the list of availableTokenIds
        for(uint256 i = 0; i<=totalCount; i++)
            tokenAvailablity[i] = true; // Availability = true. i.e. token is avialble
    }
}
```

I'm currently working in Remix and the error that I keep getting is as follows:

```
creation of MyToken pending...

creation of MyToken errored: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "code": -32000,
  "message": "gas required exceeds allowance (20019530)"
}
```

When reading this error my first intuition was to set a higher gas limit when deploying my Smart Contract and to see what happens. I've tried doing that and have increased my Gas Limit to a very high number such as 100000000 but I would still get the same error.

There are two things that I would like to mention which I find to be weird:

- Deploying to Rinkbey does not give this error. Other test networks do.
- Removing the for loop allows for the contract to be deployed with no problem at all.

Could somebody please help me with this?

Comment: There are a few possibilities. I got this exact error a couple of weeks ago, and it was actually misleading. The real problem was a bug in my code causing an error (which I still have not fixed). Another possibility is that you are exceeding the block gas size limit, but in this case I don't think a for loop of 2000 items would cause that. Then again, I can't see any problems with the for loop from glancing at it, so maybe `totalCount` is too high. Try a lower number, perhaps `10`, and see if your transaction succeeds. That way you'll know if it's a problem with gas or if theres a code mistake

Comment: The loop would write 2,000 storage slot, each slot modification cost 20,000 gas, so it will use at leas 40,000,000 gas. For the transaction to execute a block gas limit has to be at least 40M gas. I'd suggest avoiding any loop, or allowing to execute in batches.